# Not able to retrieve entire data from view created in oracle

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using a view to display the data in my web application. I am using Java script to retrieve data to the front end, but I am able to only fetch 258 records rather than the entire records. The data is getting filtered somewhere. Can some one help me to resolve the issue?

Comment: This somewhere is certainly in you webpage. Check the webpage display page size. Does it allows more records.

Comment: I have to display one record at a time , not all at a time when I try to do this for the first 250 records I am able to show the data but from the next record it says data not found.

Comment: And you are sure you have more rows in your database. In that case can you post your code for others to have look on.

Comment: Please share some parts of your code along with any pics that shows the problem